# SQLalchemy table with multiple foreign keys from other tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to learn `sqlalchemy` and am a bit confused on creating an object that will go into a table that has foreign keys to two other tables. Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do. I'm making a recipe database and have three tables: `recipes`, `ingredients`, and `recipe_ingredients`. `recipe_ingredients` links together ingredients to recipes. I have this build up:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Text, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine(u'sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()

class Recipe(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'recipes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

    recipe_ingredient = relationship('RecipeIngredient', back_populates='recipe')

class Ingredient(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ingredients'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

    recipe_ingredient = relationship('RecipeIngredient', back_populates='ingredient')

class RecipeIngredient(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe_ingredients'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipe_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('recipes.id'))
    ingredient_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('ingredients.id'))

    recipe = relationship('Recipe', back_populates='recipe_ingredient')
    ingredient = relationship('Ingredient', back_populates='recipe_ingredient')

ham = Ingredient(name='cereal')
bread = Ingredient(name='milk')
cheese = Ingredient(name='cheese')
sandwich = Recipe(name='ham and cheese')
# Now I'm not sure how to link theses
link1 = RecipeIngredient(recipe_id=sandwich.id, ingredient_id=ham.id)
link2 = RecipeIngredient(recipe_id=sandwich.id, ingredient_id=bread.id)
link3 = RecipeIngredient(recipe_id=sandwich.id, ingredient_id=cheese.id)

session.add_all([ham, bread, cheese, sandwich, link1, link2, link3])
session.commit()
```

And this doesn't work because of the `RecipeIngredient` objects. How am I able to link the foreign keys like this to create those objects?

Comment: Since this was marked as a duplicate, I can't leave an answer.

All that I did was add

`Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`

after the class definitions (ie. before the 'ham =' line), and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Use a combination of ForeignKeyConstraint and  ForeignKey.

```
    from sqlalchemy import ForeignKeyConstraint

    class RecipeIngredient(Base):
        ...
        recipe_id = Column(Integer, ForeinKey('recipes.id'))
        ingredient_id = Column(Integer)

        __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["ingrediants_id"],
            ["ingredients.id"]
        ),)
        ...
```